# How to save the exact state of the programe for specific user?

Tags: java

So I've been making this program in java that's going to store data for users. I've already made login and registration screen using sqlite database. And now, after the user logs in, the main screen opens, and here the user can add stuff (just text for now). This text is stored in form of JLabels on the main screen of the program. But what i don't know is, how to open everything that user changed last time he used the program? And of course for each user it has to be different.

Comment: get user id when login .save user data with that id

Comment: That was my first idea, and i probably could find a way to save data in another table, but how do i open that data and present it in, for example, JLabel form on my screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The premise behind the answer is:

- Read all the labels the user has changed/added/etc...
- Save it to somewhere where you can read it again.
- Load it once the user logs in again

Override the `WindowClosing` of your JFrame:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {

    }
});
```

Run through each Control on the Frame (or wherever you store them):

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
    String savedData = "";
    for (Component c: getComponents()) {
        if (c instanceof JLabel) {
            savedData += ((JLabel)c).getText() + "\n";
        }
    }
    //Save Data to file
    //OR write to sqlite database in the current users row
}
```

So now that you have the information saved, you will want to load it again if that user logs in at another time. To do that, you would override the `WindowOpened` event. Or alternatively, just call a function you make after the login is successful if doing so does not create a new window.

```
public Form1() {
    initializeComponents();
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
            //Read data (Depends on the method you choose to save)
            Label label = new Label(data);
            add(label);
        }
    });
}
```